# Python: Scope of function parameters

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort

I am studying QuickSort and I practice using Python to complete it. But something happened that I didn't expect. It seems that my QuickSort function only sort once. Why?

```
array = [3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 0, 8, 9]


def quick_sort(array):
    if len(array) <= 1:
        # print(array)
        # print('')
        return
    else:
        # print(array)
        # print('')
        pivot = array[0]
        i = 1
        j = len(array) - 1
        while i != j:
            while array[j] >= pivot and i < j:
                j -= 1
            while array[i] <= pivot and i < j:
                i += 1
            if i < j:
                array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
                # print(array)
                # print('')
        if array[0] > array[i]:
            array[0], array[i] = array[i], array[0]
        # print(array)
        # print('')
        array_left = array[0:i]
        array_right = array[i + 1:]
        quick_sort(array_left)
        quick_sort(array_right)


def test_quick_sort():

    # print(array)
    quick_sort(array)
    print(array)


test_quick_sort()
```

The output is [2, 1, 0, 3, 6, 7, 5, 4, 8, 9].
If you cancel all the #,you can see the output of each step which is absolutely correctly.

Comment: You sort the sub-arrays at the end, but these are copies of parts of the original array, and you don't copy them back.

Comment: You are also reading and writing the array in the same function - you're better off making a copy of the array for modifying, and treating the input as read-only.

Comment: @match The reason quicksort is so fast is that it can be used in-place. Although even in-place quicksort can be O(n^2) for a bad choice of pivots, making copies *guarantees* you will take O(n^2) time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python, when you slice a list, a new list is created with the values.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = list1[:3] #[1, 2, 3]
list2[0] = 5 #[5, 2, 3]

print(list1, list2) #[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [5, 2, 3]
```

Any changes made to the sliced list is not reflected in the original one.

Within your quick_sort function, you sliced the list into left and right portions and called quick_sort on them. This does not affect the order of the original list.

To resolve this, modify your function to instead take in a list together with the start and end index of where to sort.

```
def quick_sort(array, start, end):
    if end - start <= 1:
        return
    else:
        pivot = array[start]
        i = start + 1
        j = end - 1
        while i != j:
            while array[j] >= pivot and i < j:
                j -= 1
            while array[i] <= pivot and i < j:
                i += 1
            if i < j:
                array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
        if array[start] > array[i]:
            array[start], array[i] = array[i], array[start]
        quick_sort(array, start, i)
        quick_sort(array, i, end)
```